# Kotlin - Init Block in Serializable Class can only read default property values

Tags: firebase, class, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, serialization

For some reason whenever I try to access the properties of this serializable class inside of the init block, only the default values are printed. I'm using firebase to read data in to this class, which is working as expected. I want to change a boolean value of the class based on the venueName parameter, but can't as only the default venue name is being accessed

```
class Venue(val venueName: String = "defaultName", val venueImageUrl: String = "", var venueImageName: String = "", val events: List<Event> = emptyList(), var isAd: Boolean = false, var isPromoVenue: Boolean = false

) : Serializable {
    val vName = venueName
    init {
        println(vName)
    }
}
#prints("defaultName") for each object created.
```

Answer (score 2):

This quote from the documentation

> [Pass a custom Java object, if the class that defines it has a default constructor that takes no arguments and has public getters for the properties to be assigned.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

implies that the instance is created by reflection using the default constructor (equivalent to `Venue()` in this case) and any `init` block would be executed then. Fields are set by reflection too after the instance is constructed (since setters aren't required).

`Serializable` shouldn't be relevant here (but its own mechanism doesn't call `Venue`'s constructor at all, so you wouldn't even see `defaultName` printed).

As a workaround, you could create a helper class without `init`

```
class VenueDTO(val venueName: String = "defaultName", val venueImageUrl: String = "", val venueImageName: String = "", val events: List<Event> = emptyList(), val isAd: Boolean = false, val isPromoVenue: Boolean = false) : Serializable {
    val asVenue get() = Venue(this)
}

class Venue(val asDto: VenueDTO) {
    val vName = venueName
    init {
        println(vName)
    }
}
```

store `VenueDTO` in Firebase and translate it to `Venue` immediately when it's retrieved.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just wondering is there anyway to override the read object method?

Comment: "is there anyway to override the read object method" The one used by `Serializable` yes, but as explained above Firebase probably doesn't use it.